# Minecraft Bukkit server spams logfile - Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, server, upstart, log, minecraft

I have a virtual server (Ubuntu 12.04) and a serious problem with Minecraft/Bukkit. I've installed a fresh bukkit 1.6.4 on my virtual server and made some upstart script for it.

Here is the /etc/init/minecraft-server.conf

```
start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [^2345]

console log
chdir /srv/minecraft/server-kronos
setuid minecraft
setgid minecraft

respawn
respawn limit 20 5

exec java -Xms1024M -Xmx1536M -jar craftbukkit.jar -o true --log-limit 1000
```

If I start the server via `initctl start minecraft-server` the server itself runs fine and I can play on it but the logfile is spammed extremely fast.

Everytime it is started, it generates like 1 MB/s (!!) of data in the logfile.
The logfile /var/log/minecraft-server.log looks like this:

```
<<<<<<<<<<<<...
```

The server spams millions of these "<" symbols in the logfile.

Any ideas?

Help would be highly appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out :) :) :)

The problem was the missing --noconsole option. The console of the Minecraft server is on per default and got some commands that it shouldn't get, then it replied "<" everytime and this output was piped into the logfile constantly.

Now my upstart script looks like this and it works fine:

```
start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [^2345]

console log
chdir /srv/minecraft/server-kronos
setuid root
setgid root

respawn
respawn limit 20 5

exec java -Xms1024M -Xmx1536M -jar craftbukkit.jar -o true --noconsole
```

Comment: Just found this [Bukkit and Upstart](https://forums.bukkit.org/threads/bukkit-1-7-9-and-upstart.287814/) on the official bukkit forum...they had the same problem